# post error 404 page not found

Tags: jquery

The below code gives me error 404 page not found (response into firebug) but the same code runs perfectly at localhost.

```
function simplemaps_state_clicked(id, name) {
    $.post("home/get_metrix", {
        id: id
    }).done(function (data) {
        document.getElementById('simplemaps').innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this :

```
$.post("home/get_metrix", { id: id })
```

with

```
$.post("/home/get_metrix", { id: id })
```

As it is got getting the root of the url

Comment: Put a / before the home in the above line

Comment: Please check the path it is firing to in firebug. You can then paste the URL in your browser and can cross check whether you are pointing to the correct URL or not.

Comment: @PrabhanjanKumarMahapatra: I applied the formatting again it makes it more readable and also ensure any characters in the code which you intended to be displayed are preserved and displayed :)